# Toggle Plane Detection (Unity + ARKit)

Tags: unity-game-engine, arkit

My aim is to have a UI button/switch that allows me to enable and disable plane detection on command. I have tried several methods but non seem to work for me. Currently using the ExampleScene from the ARKit plugin for Unity, I feel that most of the tinkering has to be done through the HitTestExample script. Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `UnityARKitScene`. There is an object `ARKitControl` with script `UnityARKitControl`.